# External Scripts connnecting miner to Zabbix getting zero data

Tags: python, zabbix, mining, external-script

I'm trying the external script here https://github.com/AndOr0812/zabbix-antminer And after I configured the scripts and proxy settings, I was keeping getting zero data, both in Zabbix and the commandline. I have done chmod 755 and disabled firewall. It shows "[107] Transport endpoint is not connected". Any ideas on what to check/debugg?

Comment: Zabbix server -> (1) -> Zabbix proxy -> (2) -> external script -> (3) -> antminer
Do you know in which step the problem occurs? Can you isolate that step? Do you have something else that is working over the connection?

Comment: In (2) the script I think. After I tried another script written in shell (https://github.com/dima666d/antminerS9i), it works. However, the python based script is not working. I'm asking if there are additional configurations needed for the python script above? https://github.com/AndOr0812/zabbix-antminer

Comment: The next step is trying to call the `./antminer-zbx-chk  <host> <port> <username> <password> <item>` from the console and look at the response.

Comment: I tried this step and ends up with getting a 0 of the item value. On the Zabbix terminal, all items were loaded successfully but getting 0s too. When I let the code to print out the error message, it says "[107] Transport endpoint is not connected"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `antminer-zbx-chk` is responsible for your problems:
When the script is replaced by `echo 0`, is the error message gone?

Look on internet for your error message, this seems to be a timeout value. On https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/8466-many-time_wait-connection/page2 in issue with getpeername is mentioned. Maybe look into that.

Look how long the external script takes:

```
time ./antminer-zbx-chk  <host> <port> <username> <password> <item>
```

When it takes more then 10 seconds you must look for an async solution.
When it takes 1-10 you can consider an async solution.

Async: One job that fires the antminer in the background and returns before a result is given. Another job that takes a look at the result or even betterL
Make a script calling antminer and use zabbix_sender when a result is found.

Comment: When it is echo 0 then it echo everything as zero. When it is echo 1, then every parametrers will be 1.

Comment: After I tried another script written in shell (github.com/dima666d/antminerS9i), it works. However, the python based script is not working.

Comment: So the question what to debug/test is solved: the python script. The zabbix-antminer is for python 3 and zabbix 3, perhaps the code is not compatible with your environment. Look for timeout values, dns, getpeername, try calling a script that calls antminer with nohup or try to contact the author of the script.